# Parse Jackson Style JSON in Flutter

Tags: json, parsing, dart, flutter, jackson

I have a JSON response. This response comes from server using Jackson writing Java.

Response JSON contains a lot of nested objects,array etc. You know that if JSON has same object, first object has a lot of things, another have just id.

{
        "json_id": "4eca9663-0522-4411-ba10-37b1028ac61a",

```
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "key": value,
    "city": {
        "json_id": "8b5e8a17-442f-478e-982f-ade06996d3cf",
         "name": "Ankara",  
    },
    {cities:[
        { // actually this city refer Ankara. this is Ankara json_id above
            "8b5e8a17-442f-478e-982f-ade06996d3cf"
        },
        {
            "json_id":feb538a8-31b3-49a5-a424-0bf46f429a0d,
            "name": "İstanbul"
        }
    ]}
```

I am trying to Parse it on Flutter. Is there any library for this?

Answer (score 0):

Link - https://app.quicktype.io/

Above link can help you to parse JSON response in flutter

Comment: Consider providing more context. See the [how to answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553) about link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code shows how to parse JSON response and get data from it:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getJSONData(); //method
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("my JSON app")),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: new Text(data[index]['name'] ?? ''),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> getJSONData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
      data = convertDataToJson;
    });
  }
}
```

You can adapt it to your needs.